# Can I optimize for the zIIP processor?

Tags: db2, optimization, db2-zos

Is it possible to change SQL in a z/OS mainframe COBOL application so that it becomes eligible to be directed to the IBM System z Integrated Information Processor (zIIP)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I posted this answer in response to the same question on [StackOverflow](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_12.0.0/intro/src/tpc/db2z_distributeddatafacility.html), so here is a re-post:

---

An important distinction to make is that according to IBM, zIIP is only available for "eligible database workloads", and those "eligible" loads are mostly targeted for large BI/ERP/CRM solutions that run on distributed servers, which are connecting through [DDF (Distributed Data Facility)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_12.0.0/intro/src/tpc/db2z_distributeddatafacility.html) over TCP/IP.

[IBM has a list](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_12.0.0/perf/src/tpc/db2z_ibmziip.html) of DB2 workloads that can utilize zIIP.  These include:

- DDF server threads that process SQL requests from applications that
  access DB2 by TCP/IP (up to 60%)
- Parallel child processes. A portion of each
  child process executes under a dependent enclave SRB if it processes
  on behalf of an application that originated from an allied address
  space, or under an independent enclave SRB if the processing is
  performed on behalf of a remote application that accesses DB2 by
  TCP/IP. The enclave priority is inherited from the invoking allied
  address space for a dependent enclave or from the main DDF server
  thread enclave classification for an independent enclave. (Versions up 
  to 11 allowed 80% to run on zIIP, v12 upped this to 100% eligible).
- Utility index build and maintenance processes for the LOAD, REORG, and
  REBUILD INDEX utilities.

And if you're on DB2 v10, you can also use zIIP with:

- Remote native SQL procedures.
- XML Schema validation and non-validation parsing.
- DB2 utility functions for maintaining index structures.
- Certain portions of processing for the RUNSTATS utility.
- Prefetch and deferred write processing for the DB2 buffer pool

Version 11 added the following:

- Asynchronous enclave SRBs (service request blocks) that execute in the 
  Db2 ssnmMSTR, ssnmDBM1 and ssnmDIST address spaces, with the exception 
  of p-lock negotiation processing. These processes include Db2 buffer pool
  processing for prefetch, deferred write, page set castout, log read, and
  log write processing. Additional eligible processes include index 
  pseudo-delete and XML multi version document cleanup processing.

Version 12 allowed parallel child tasks to go 100% to zIIP after a certain threshold of CPU usage.

So, if you're using COBOL programs, it would appear that IBM does not intend for you to use zIIP with these workloads.  You can still take advantage of zIIP with utilites (LOAD, REORG), and some steps of the RUNSTATS utility, so it may still be worthwhile to have some zIIP.

Comment: @PatrickBossman, thanks for the edit. The notification reminded me that this needed to be updated for versions newer than v10! I have added some sections regarding v11 and v12.

Answer (score 1):

The point of zIIP processors is that you can't run z/OS code on them.  Your COBOL code won't run on them.  However, according to [this article](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/z/hardware/features/ziip/index.html) DB/2 for z/OS is an eligible workload to run on a zIIP processor.  I presume your COBOL code has embedded SQL.  Embedded SQL architectures are actually preprocessors that generate code that sends the query off to the database behind the scenes, so your SQL code is going to run on the DB server.

If the COBOL programme is sending SQL to the DB/2 server via TCP/IP (DRDA) then it should run on the zIIP if the DB/2 server is configured to run on it.  If the COBOL code is doing a lot of client-side processing or it's not using this then this will not be eligible.  Chances are the COBOL app is not using DRDA, though.

Comment: You are correct is assuming this is an embedded SQL COBOL application, which is why I'm interested in the DB2 load being eligible for zIIP.  The article you cite states that DB2 is eligible for "portions of eligible data serving".  Any idea what that means, and if there is something to be done in the SQL, or application on the whole, to increase this eligibility?

Comment: Will look into the DRDA issue, thanks.  +1 but still not closing in the hope of getting more hard to find info.

Comment: Depending on how your COBOL application connects to the DB/2 server it may be constrained to sit on the same processor, in which case you can only use the local DB/2 capacity.  If you can configure the COBOL app to connect over TCP/IP then you may be able to hit a DB/2 server running on a zIIP.

Answer (score 0):

When Db2 executes a query using CPU parallelism, the parallel child tasks qualify for zIIP offload.  This is typically only viable for queries that are not transactional in nature (eg. consume more than a cpu second per execution).